# Touch input not detected on Touch Monitor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Currently, I'm facing an issue, the vb.net XAML interface cannot detect touch input.
When I use mouse input to click the button, the event can be fired.
But when I use Touch input, it is nothing happens to the UI. All the elements' event cannot be triggered.
Textbox, Button, Checkbox, etc.

I had tried for StylusUp/Down, TouchUp/Down

Here is my code

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TCPIP"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closed="Window_Closed" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        
    <Button Name="Touch" Content="Click This" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Touch_Click" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>

    <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Content="Send Dummy" Name="Dummy" Click="Dummy_Click"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="txtAdd" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="114"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtSend" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Send" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="114" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtStatus" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Status" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtReceived" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Receive" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="245" Height="105"/>

</Grid>
```